# invalid application of 'sizeof' to an incomplete type

Tags: c++, c

I am using an external library written in c. Our application code is written in c++.

The application code try to use an include file which contains (very simplified) the following piece of code:

```
#pragma once
#pragma pack(push, 1)

struct someQueue 
{
    struct descExtra {
        unsigned int ndescs;
    } desc;
};

#pragma pack(pop)

static inline void someQueue_allocate(unsigned int num)
{
    unsigned int someSize = sizeof(struct someQueue) + num * sizeof(struct descExtra);
}
```

Now as said this is external code which I do not want to modify. When I include this header from a "C" file, it compiles. When I include this header file from a c++ file it gives me a compile error:

```
error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to an incomplete type descExtra
```

By declaring the structure inside the struct somequeue it is not accessible outside and therefore it cannot determine its size... i think? Moving this outside the somequeue struct and it will compile.

So is my understanding correct?
Why is this allowed in C but not in C++?

Can I work around this or do I need to have a c wrapper to include this header and implementation (which I not prefer..)

Comment: Replace `sizeof(struct descExtra)` with `sizeof(struct someQueue::descExtra)`

Comment: Would it be feasible to add an identical definition of `struct descExtra` (with the same pack pragma) to the code before the inclusion of the header?

Comment: EddyZ, `sizeof(struct someQueue) + num * sizeof(struct descExtra)` is suspicious.  _Why_ do you want to compute this size?  I suspect if you posted the higher level problem, you would get a better overall answer.

Answer (score 3):

It's because `struct descExtra` is not defined. `someQueue::descExtra` is however defined, so instead do:

```
sizeof(someQueue::descExtra);
```

If you can't change the code to be valid for both C and C++, you might want consider using a C compiler for the C code.

Comment: From what OP has said, the C code is in a third-party header, so changing it to C++ compatibility may not be an option.

Comment: @AdrianMole Yes, that may be a problem.  Added a possible workaround.

Comment: I'd recommend a C compiler for C code even (or *especially*) if it is also accepted by a C++ compiler.

Answer (score 2):

This is allowed in C but not in C++ because these are two completely different programming languages.

In C++ this class is `someQueue::descExtra`, `descExtra` is a member of the `someQueue` class. There is no class `descExtra` when the shown code is parsed as C++.

One possible solution is to deploy a liberal sprinkling of

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
```

in order to supply both C and C++ alternatives.

Comment: From what OP has said, the C code is in a third-party header, so changing it to C++ compatibility may not be an option.

Comment: oke clear. the fact that it is code which resides in an external library and therefore cannot/would like not to, modify that code restricts me to use a c wrapper. Thanks for the quick responses.

Comment: If the header cannot be modified, an alternative is to use a separate C++ shim/shadow header file, which mimic/mirrors the unmodifiable C header file.

Comment: Can `extern "C"` be used?

Comment: @ikegami Don't believe so.  That just affects symbol mangling.

Answer (score 1):

You are partially right, In C++ when you declare nested struct, it's not accessible the same way as in C.
C code:

```c
struct A{
   struct B{};
};
int main(void){
 int size = sizeof(struct B); // Compiles fine
}
```

But in C++, when you declare a nested structure, the structure that is not nested act like a namespace and therefore you can access the nested structure like this
C++ code:

```cpp
struct A{
   struct B{};
};
int main(void){
 int size = sizeof(A::B); // Compiles fine
}
```

In C++ the "real" name of `struct B` is actually `A::B`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `descExtra` is a nested type and so when you write `sizeof(struct descExtra)`, it declares a new class type `descExtra` in the enclosing scope and then we try to apply `sizeof` to this **incomplete type** which gives us the mentioned error.

A contrived example to clear this up further:

```
int main()
{
    struct C{
    struct P{};
    };
    //----------------vvvvvvvv--->this DECLARES a new class type called P in main()
    std::cout<<sizeof(struct P);//error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘main()::P’
    return 0;
}
```

So to solve this replace `sizeof(struct descExtra)` with `sizeof(struct someQueue::descExtra)`

Comment: From what OP has said, the C code is in a third-party header, so changing it to C++ compatibility may not be an option.

Comment: @AdrianMole I've said that we can replace `struct descExtra` with `struct someQueue::descExtra` inside the sizeof. That is C compatible  right? See my comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73291695/invalid-application-of-sizeof-to-an-incomplete-type/73291802#comment129435948_73291695)

Comment: Editing the 3rd-party header may not be an option and is probably not advisable, even if it is.

Comment: @AdrianMole Oh, you meant that. Ok, i agree. But still I think we can at least tell OP what the problem is.

Comment: Also, C doesn't have a `::` operator, or anything remotely resembling it.

Comment: @AdrianMole Ok, then i guess my answer is purely for C++. I only saw the `c++` tag in the question.

Comment: Thanks Jason and Adrian, I must have included the "C" tag sorry for that. Thanks for explaining and its clear. As I don't want to modify the third party library I need to stick with a "C" wrapper. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

It *might* be feasible to redefine `struct descExtra` outside the header file:

**header_wrapper.h**

```
#ifndef HEADER_WRAPPER_H__INCLUDED
#define HEADER_WRAPPER_H__INCLUDED

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#pragma pack(push, 1)

struct descExtra {
    unsigned int ndescs;
};

#pragma pack(pop)

#include "header.h" // defines struct someQueue, struct someQueue::descExtra, and someQueue_allocate()

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif /* HEADER_WRAPPER_H__INCLUDED */
```

It really depends on how complicated the real `struct descExtra` is and what else it depends on.

Comment: `#pragma pack` looks like a non-standard compiler extension.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Yes, it's for MSVC. I copied it from OP's code because it was used around the definition of `struct someQueue` and the definition of `struct descExtra` defined within `struct someQueue` in the original code. (`#pragma pack(pop)` undoes the effect of the previous `#pragma pack(push, X)`.)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica And also supported by GCC and probably Clang....